# how to pass same fetched data on my everypage on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my controller code

```
 public function index()
{
    $this->load->model("mod_home");
    $data['avoinics'] = $this->mod_home->getAvoinics();
    $data['dir']="home";
    $data['page']="index";
    $this->load->view('main',$data);
}
```

for another page

```
 public function about()
{
    $this->load->model("mod_home");
    $data['avoinics'] = $this->mod_home->getAvoinics();
    $data['dir']="home";
    $data['page']="about";
    $this->load->view('main',$data);
}
```

1. But i don't want to send $data['avoinics'] again again. Is there any way to access a data from anypage.
2. How to use same data in a single view more than time.

   ```
            foreach($avoinics as $avoinics):
                $name=$avoinics->sc_name;

                 echo '<li><a href="" title="">'.$name.'</a></li>';

                 endforeach;
   ```

if i use it again on same view page it's sowing error...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can:

Create a global array

```
private $data = array();
```

In constructor

```
$this->load->model("mod_home");
$this->data['avoinics'] = $this->mod_home->getAvoinics();
```

Now your function will look like this

```
public function index() {
    $this->data['dir']="home";
    $this->data['page']="index";
    $this->load->view('main',$this->data);
}
```

For second part, do not change the variable value

```
foreach($avoinics as $record){
    echo '<li><a href="" title="">'.$record['name'].'</a></li>';
}
```

`$avoinics` is intact now. You can use it again until you do not modify it.

Comment: This is not working. Can you please suggest me what else i can go for?

Answer (score 0):

A good example you might easily understand is when you need to call certain scripts or css files for a specific controller. You won't call it in every single page but yes in the constructor.

```
class yourController extends CI_Controller
{
   private $data;

   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->data['css'] = array('file1.css', 'file2.css');
      $this->data['js']  = array('jquery.min.js', 'jquery-ui.min.js');
   }

   public function index()
   {
      $this->load->view('yourView', $this->data);
   }

   public function about()
   {
      $this->load->view('yourView', $this->data);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you [to extend core](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html) ci_controller with my_controller and declare there your variable in constructor. Then in your new controllers extend your my_controller where you will have variable declaration.